# Linking JavaVM Framework to Xcode - objective C

Tags: xcode, frameworks, jvm, java-native-interface

O.K. I am new to xcode/objective c and have an issue, I have read all the previous comments about linking a framework to and IOS app but it just wont work for me. There must be some dumb mistake I am making so here is what I have done.

- Created a new app just to test the JVM-JNI
- Linked the JavaVM.framework via the drag and drop method, result was could not access the .h files.
- Linked the JavaVM.framework via the Build Phases - Link Binaries With Libraries Method, gives the exact same result.

Is there a tutorial out there somewhere that takes us newbies through the steps (not just refer to read it up somewhere) any help would be appreciated.